# Boolean values in ngIf

Tags: templates, angular

I have the following code in my Angular2 Template:

```
<li>Gender: <span *ng-if="rating.isMale">Male</span><span *ng-if="!rating.isMale">Female</span></li>
```

Where rating.isMale is a boolean. But I get this error in the console:

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ng-if' since it isn't a known native property
>   ("ode}}
>
> Age: {{rating.age}}
>
> Gender: ]*ng-if="rating.isMale">MaleFemale
>
> <"): RatingComponent@12:38 Property binding ng-if not used by any directive on an embedded template ("untryCode}}
>
> Age: {{rating.age}}
>
> Gender: [ERROR ->]MaleFemale
>
> "): RatingComponent@12:32 Can't bind to 'ng-if' since it isn't a known native property (" {{rating.age}}
>
> Gender: Male]*ng-if="!rating.isMale">Female
>
> "): RatingComponent@12:78 Property binding ng-if not used by any directive on an embedded template ("i>Age:
>   {{rating.age}}
>
> Gender: Male[ERROR ->]Female
>
> "): RatingComponent@12:72

What is the correct way of accomplishing to write the two answers based on the boolean as I wish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ng-if="boolean"` is now `*ngIf="boolean"` in Angular2